# Validate a string to be one of two lengths

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model

Is it possible to use ASP MVC's `DataAnnotation` to require a string to be one of two lengths? This example obviously doesn't work but I am thinking of something along these lines

```
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Agent ID")]
    [StringLength(8) || StringLength(10)]
    public string AgentId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own validation attribute to handle it:

```
public class UserStringLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private int _lenght1;
        private int _lenght2;


        public UserStringLengthAttribute(int lenght2, int lenght1)
        {
            _lenght2 = lenght2;
            _lenght1 = lenght1;
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            var typedvalue = (string) value;
            if (typedvalue.Length != _lenght1 || typedvalue.Length != _lenght2)
            {
                ErrorMessage = string.Format("Length should be {0} or {1}", _lenght1, _lenght2);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And use it:

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Agent ID")]
[UserStringLength(8,10)]
public string AgentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that . Do a custom validator that inherits from StringLength and this will work for both client and server side

```
public class CustomStringLengthAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
    {
        private readonly int _firstLength;
        private readonly int _secondLength;


        public CustomStringLengthAttribute(int firstLength, int secondLength)
            : base(firstLength)
        {
            _firstLength = firstLength;
            _secondLength = secondLength;

        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {

            int valueTobeValidate = value.ToString().Length;

            if (valueTobeValidate == _firstLength)
            {
                return base.IsValid(value);
            }

            if (valueTobeValidate == _secondLength)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return base.IsValid(value);

        }
    }
```

and register the adapter in the Appplication_start of the Global.asax.cs

```
 DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(CustomStringLengthAttribute), typeof(StringLengthAttributeAdapter));
```